# Get the image (picture) of an django database using django-image-cropping and easy-thumbnails

Tags: python, django, easy-thumbnails

I have an django installation with the plugins django-image-cropping and easy-thumbnails in use.

I want to add users pictures to there vCard using vObject.

```
models.py:
(...)
class Person(TranslatableModel):
    (...)
    pic = ImageCropField(_(u"profile picture"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=settings.USER_PICTURE_DIR,
    )
    picture_cropped = ImageRatioField(
        'pic',
        '{}x{}'.format(*settings.USER_PICTURE_SIZE)
    )
(...)
```

So far all I can find about this topic is, how to get an URL to the original Picture, but I don't know how to get the cropped Picture nor do I know how to get the Picture itself and not an URL nor a pseudo-file-type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an older version of `django-image-cropping` as the `ImageCropField` does no longer exist in recent versions.

For the latest version it is documented how to get the URL for a cropped thumbnail from your python code: https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping#frontend

```
from image_cropping.utils import get_backend
thumbnail_url = get_backend().get_thumbnail_url(
    yourmodel.image,
    {
        'size': (430, 360),
        'box': yourmodel.cropping,
        'crop': True,
        'detail': True,
    }
)
```

In [older versions you would use](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping/blob/5e2e152d788c4e9d5937c242335292b00bec0d2d/README.rst):

```
from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer
thumbnail_url = get_thumbnailer(yourmodel.image).get_thumbnail({
    'size': (430, 360),
    'box': yourmodel.cropping,
    'crop': True,
    'detail': True,
}).url
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What i needed was:
`get_thumbnailer(person.pic).get_thumbnail(...).path` but you got me on the right track.